# Replace a multiline pattern with re.sub

Tags: python, regex

In the following string, I'd like to replace all `BeginHello...EndHello` blocks that contain `haha` by `''`:

```
s = """BeginHello
sqdhaha
fsqd
EndHello

BeginHello
1231323
EndHello

BeginHello
qsd
qsd
haha
qsd
EndHello
BeginHello
azeazezae
azeaze
EndHello
"""
```

This code:

```
import re
s = re.sub(r'BeginHello.*haha.*EndHello', '', s)
print s
```

does not work here: nothing is deleted.

**How to use such a regex for a multiline pattern with Python `re.sub`?**

Comment: Use `\n` for a new line.

Comment: Use `r'(?s)BeginHello(?:(?!BeginHello|EndHello|haha).)*haha.*?EndHello'` or `(?s)BeginHello(?:(?!BeginHello|haha).)*?haha.*?EndHello`

Comment: without re `>>> s.replace("BeginHello", "EndHello")`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What do you mean, can you post an answer explaining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try matching using the following pattern:

```
BeginHello((?!\bEndHello\b).)*?haha.*?EndHello
```

This matches an initial `BeginHello`.  Then, it uses a tempered dot:

```
((?!\bEndHello\b).)*?
```

to consume anything so long as we do not hit `EndHello`.  This dot is also lazy, and will stop before hitting `haha`.  Effectively, using the above dot means we will only consume without hitting either `EndHello` or `haha`.  Then, assuming the match works so far, we would consume `haha`, followed by the nearest `EndHello`.

```
s = re.sub(r'BeginHello((?!\bEndHello\b).)*?haha.*?EndHello', '', s,
    flags=re.DOTALL)
print s



BeginHello
1231323
EndHello


BeginHello
azeazezae
azeaze
EndHello
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Isn't there a solution that avoids to repeat `EndHello` in the regex twice?

Comment: Why does that bother you?  Shouldn't performance be the major concern?  If the answer works and runs reasonably well, then there is no reason to not use it IMHO.

Comment: Yes, it was just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

You want `re.DOTALL`. This basically allows `.` to match any character including `\n`

```
import re
s = re.sub(r'BeginHello.*?haha.*?EndHello', '', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
print s
```

Comment: Why would anyone want to use `re.M` with your pattern? That does not allow `.` to match `\n`.

Comment: I tried with [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M) but it does not work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I got mixed up with ```re.DOTALL```

Comment: @TheoEmms With your current solution, the output is empty (probably because of "greedy" regex).

Comment: You're right... I've obviously not used regex enough recently... Answer is updated

Comment: The answer is wrong. You can't use `.*` or `.*?` here with any options. You need a tempered greedy token, unrolled or not.